# can''t enable http2 apache on debian jessie

Tags: debian, apache2, debian-jessie, http2

I have updated Apache2 on Debian Jesie using testing repository

https://www.shivering-isles.com/http-2-getting-ready-on-debian-with-apache2/

now i have:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Debian)
Server built:   2017-09-23T22:08:01
```

an2mod http2 ..done

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Sep 25 16:42 http2.load -> ../mods-available/http2.load
```

/etc/apache2/conf-available/http2.conf .... edited

....

but checking https://www.tecnocroci.it HTTP2 doesn't work

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes sure service apache restart

Answer (score 1):

When I check the site in SSLLabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.tecnocroci.it I see a few things:

1. This site supports ALPN so you are using an up to date OpenSSL version as required by some browsers for HTTP/2. This is a common problem but doesn’t appear to be your problem.
2. This site supports modern GCM ciphers as required by by some browsers for HTTP/2. This is a common problem but doesn’t appear to be your problem.
3. The site does not support HTTP/2.

At this point all I can guess is one of two things:

1. You’ve forgotten to include `Protocols h2 http1.1` in your config as per the guide who’s link you included.
2. You have something in front of your Apache (e.g. a load balancer or other infrastructure) which doesn’t support HTTP/2.